# Toolbar not display on catalog search magento 2.x luma theme

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, magento2.0.17

When I search any product Toolbar and Pagination is not showing on the Catalog Search page.

But it is Working on my local server.

[image]
[image]

Magento V 2.0.17 Custom Luma theme
PHP 7.0.3

Comment: Check extension if you are using for product list.

Comment: Thank you so much issue is resolved. I have disabled product related extension. It is working fine.

Comment: Whats the issue? I think you were using magebees extension which removes the toolbar from search.

Comment: It is third party extesion for advanced sortby product.

Comment: Ok. Happy Coding.